# Select first TD in every row of first table w/ jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to select the first TD of every table row where the following conditions are met:

1. TD does not have colspan
2. TD in the first table and not any of the nested ones

The following does not work for me...

```
$("table:first > td:first-child").not("[colspan]").css("background-color","red");
```

Comment: Could you post an example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: *"Also parent > child selector is depricated..."* No it isn't. Only the use of it without the left side operand is deprecated. The `>` is a valid CSS selector, so it doesn't make sense to deprecate it. But to use it with only one operand is not valid CSS, so it does makes sense to deprecate that specific behavior.

Comment: @am not i am -- You're right. It's $("> elem", context) is deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To limit to the `td`s of the outer table, you can drill down to a specific level using multiple child selectors.

```
$("table:first > tbody > tr > td:first-child").not("[colspan]")
```

Note that I included `tbody`. You should explicitly include it in your table since most browsers (but not necessarily all) will inject it when missing.

---

If you have `thead` and `tfoot` elements that should be included, use `*` instead of `tbody`.

```
$("table:first > * > tr > td:first-child").not("[colspan]")
```

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to figure out a solution without parent > child selector since it's being deprecated...

Comment: @santa: No, the `parent > child` selector is not deprecated. Its use without a left hand operand is deprecated, like: `> child, context` or `$(context).find('> child')`.

Answer (score 1):

The `TD` is probably not a direct descendant of the `TABLE` anyway (there should be a `TR` in between), so just remove the `>` in teh selector:

```
$('table:first td:first-child:not([colspan])');
```

Also, I think it’s just the `> child` selector that is deprecated (when not having the parent in the selector). `parent > child` should be perfectly valid:

> Note: The $("> elem", context) selector will be deprecated in a future
>   release. Its usage is thus discouraged in lieu of using alternative
>   selectors.

Comment: I love the simplicity of this solution! But it still selects first column of the nested tables...

Comment: @santa right, I misread your question. You might have to drill down then I guess, I’ll see if I can come up with a simple solution.

Comment: Thanks @David. I'm experimenting with all sorts of crazy ideas, like: $("table:not(:gt(0)) td:first-child:not([colspan])")... :)

Comment: [:first-child](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/)  does select the first child, and only the first child. I think you want all childs of your table, but none of the tds in tables nested into your table.

Comment: @Tai Kahar Yes, first TD child in every row. :first will select just the first child...

Comment: @santa ah, now  i see what your goal was like :)

Answer (score 0):

```
/* This piece of code selects every first TD element without colspan
 * in EVERY NOT nested TABLE
 */

// Select all without colspan
$('table td:first-child:not([colspan])').filter(
    // filter out those having more than 1 parent table
    function() {
        return $(this).parents('table').length == 1
    }).css('background', 'red');
```